# Push notifications using SignalR

Tags: .net, push-notification, signalr

So I need to push notifications to different users. 
E.g: I have a table and different users are trying to populate it. I want to push notifications when a person insert a row into the table and let the other users to know.

I was thinking to use SignalR but I couldn`t find any examples (for .net)

Any ideas or tutorials which could help?

I don`t want to use the database because it will make the program to be too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use SignalR without database you can use it after the successful insertion of records in the table. e.g: You have a Method InsertRecord();

All users are calling same method to insert data in that case you have to call SignalR Hub method after data insert. Hub will notify all connected users.
For implementation of SignalR you get help from this link
[SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/)